# Suggestions for gunshot libraries

Tags: library, guns, low-budget, suggestion

Hey folks,

i am currently working on a (no)low-budget student short movie project which will be shown on a public event.

Unfortunately its a short action sequence.

Unfortunately because there is some shooting action in a scene.

Because i myself do not own a gunshot library yet, and the producer will probably eat me if i  tell him that i need 200$ to buy a complete library to use it for the 5 shots which are fired in this very short sequenze, now my question:

Has anybody got any suggestions about where i can get quality single small caliber indoor gunshots?

I am already thankful and looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: I'd search all the downloadable SFX sites e.g. http://www.sounddogs.com/ . They stock some parts of larger libraries so you could find groups of gunshots rather than individual samples that don't have any variations. The quality control is also much stricter than in e.g. FreeSound and other free or creative commons sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get the Boom Library's Designed Guns for $128, which is very reasonable.  If you're looking to spend less than that, I'm afraid you may be sacrificing quality for expense.  Try freesound.org, try recording your own gunshots, or try purchasing single gunshot sound effects from any of the various online libraries that offer single sound effect downloads (prosoundeffects.com, for example).  Those types of libraries charge about $2-3 per sound, so it's a bit pricey per sound but it's cheaper than buying a whole library if you only need a few sounds.

Comment: i would love to record them by myself, but the situation in europe is more complicated. Thuogh, if the deadline would leave the possibility to try to organise it - i would and probably will in future. Thanks for suggesting the Boom library it looks very much worth its money. 


Answer (score 1):

Did you try http://www.freesound.org/ ? Maybe you could find something useful there. Just check under what license people distribute their sounds.

Comment: was the first thing i ve checked but I want to be honest with peoples rights and the 0 licenses don`t match my cost/quality scheme.Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty happy with EFX's handgun library. It only has a six guns in it (including a couple of clips of a suppressed .22) but it might have all you need. The great thing is that it includes recordings of the guns both outdoor and indoors. Not only that, but you get recordings of individual (what I assume) to be one mic recordings - plus an extra mixed version that has more weight. It gives you that material so that you can mix and match and build the gun sound that you need. Plus it's 20 Euros which isn't too bad at all: http://www.efx-sound.com/hand-gun-pack,us,4,EFX-HAND-P.cfm